# How to add column to existing DataFrame with non matching times?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

In an existing DataFrame;

```
2019-12-02 | 1.000000 
2019-12-04 | 1.020100
2019-12-05 | 1.030301
2019-12-06 | 1.040604
2019-12-09 | 1.051010
2019-12-10 | 1.061520
```

I want to add an new columns based an existing DF or TS, with a non matching index;

```
2019-12-04  00:00:00 | A
2019-12-05  15:40:00 | B
2019-12-07  00:30:00 | C
2019-12-10  15:00:00 | D
```

with as result;

```
2019-12-02 | 1.000000 NaN
2019-12-04 | 1.020100 A
2019-12-05 | 1.030301 B
2019-12-06 | 1.040604 C
2019-12-09 | 1.051010 NaN
2019-12-10 | 1.061520 D
```

The interval in the existing DataFrame can also be smaller than 24 hours.

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                   df2, 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_index=True, 
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta(24, 'H'), 
                   direction='forward')
print (df)
                   A    B
2019-12-02  1.000000  NaN
2019-12-04  1.020100    A
2019-12-05  1.030301    B
2019-12-06  1.040604  NaN
2019-12-09  1.051010  NaN
2019-12-10  1.061520    D
```

---

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                   df2, 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_index=True, 
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta(25, 'H'), 
                   direction='forward')
print (df)
                   A    B
2019-12-02  1.000000  NaN
2019-12-04  1.020100    A
2019-12-05  1.030301    B
2019-12-06  1.040604    C
2019-12-09  1.051010  NaN
2019-12-10  1.061520    D
```

Comment: I think it doesnt work for smaller than 24 hrs intervals or non-existing values in the first DF (like the row with the C)..

Comment: @user7378715 - Answer was edited, also for 24H is not matched `C`, need `25H`.